# What is meant by pro-acinar cell?

Tags: development, embryology

What is meant by "pro-acinar cell" in the following sentence? progenitors/precursors?

> A transient decline in Neurog3 expression from E11 to E12 coincides with peak segregation of MPCs into proximal, Ptf1aNkx6-1+ bipotent progenitors (BPs) and distal, Ptf1a+Nkx6-1 pro-acinar cells (PACs).

Thanks

Comment: Could you include a link to the original source from the quote? Thanks.

Comment: With the help of Google Scholar, this is from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1534580720300162

Answer (score 2):

'[Pro-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro-)' is a general Latin preposition and English prefix with many meanings, but often in biology, as in this case, it means *"before"*.  A proacinar cell is not *yet* an acinar cell (a cell of the acinus) but will be.  A related usage occurs with peptides such as [proinsulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proinsulin).

In Latin, "[acinus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acinus#Latin)" means a cluster of grapes.  You can find 'acini' in [many places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acinus), notably exocrine glands, but in this case the pancreas is discussed.  With the help of Ms. Elbakyan, they tell quite a beautiful story, but the answer to this question is mostly in the first sentence of the abstract:  the stem cells (multipotent pancreatic progenitor cells) can become pro-acinar cells (which become secretory tissue of the acini, producing the pancreatic digestive enzymes), or else are reserved as bipotent progenitors that create the ducts and the islets of Langerhans.

Comment: what is meant by "pro-"? like pro- in English or pro from progenitor?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this omission!  I've updated the answer.